# Dataview Web Part only works when pulling 110 lines or less of SQL

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, sql-server

I recently started playing with the data view web part in SharePoint Designer. I've added a new data source and added a custom query.

Unfortunately my queries appear to be limited to returning 110 results only. Any more then on a single page view and the data doesn't display, any more then that on a multipage view and the browser returns an ambiguous error (I'm not in a position where I can edit web.config to gather more detail).

Is there something I'm missing or is the data view web part really only able to return 100 rows of SQL?

Comment: Can you post details about the error? Can you check the ULS logs for detailed error?